# Getting trouble while creating charts in a android app

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using android sales crm open source project downloaded from github can able to run it but the error came when i tried to create new activity in it in that i should add charts displaying values like number of leads,planned revenue etc the thing is in that app it is connected to odoo server my question is how to create program for that using mpandroid chart library

Comment: you can use achartengine library,it works fine

Comment: The examples of mpandroid chart are quite simple to understand. Main point would be creating chart datasets from your data that need to be plotted. Could help you out further if you face a specific problem